# Linux Hosted Agents and Azure Artifacts (Symbols Publishing)

Tags: azure-devops, azure-artifacts, symbol-server

Currently when I run the Publish symbols task on the Ubuntu hosted agent I get the following error "The current operating system is not capable of running this task. That typically means the task was written for Windows only. For example, written for Windows Desktop PowerShell."

I have run this task successfully on a Windows Agent but what I have seen it doesn't work on Linux. The only thing that I have seen that could work on Linux is SourceLink but that doesn't work with Azure DevOps Artifacts yet.

Looking around I'm not able to see any way to publish symbols to Azure DevOps artifacts on a Linux agent? Has anybody else encountered this issue and were you able to get around it?

Comment: Did you check SourceLink? what do you mean doesn't work?

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/sourcelink/blob/master/README.md -- Per this page it says "Not supported by Azure DevOps Artifacts service."

Comment: This section is about include the `pdb` files in the `nupkg`. look more above and you will see that SourceLink supported in Azure DevOps.